# Erro de extenção MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados

Montei uma pagina de códigos em meu site que busca informações do banco de dados mas no arquivo que conecta na DB e puxa as informações pertinentes esta dando um suposta erro de extensão. Este erro não aparece no localhost somente quando esta hospedado em um servidor online.O erro gerado é esse:

```
Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /CSS/function/conecta.coment.php on line 22
```

O codigo da pagina:

```
<?php

//base de dados de teste

$dbhost = 'mysql.hostinger.com.br'; // endereco do servidor de banco de dados

$dbuser = 'u28*******_fraex'; // login do banco de dados

$dbname = 'u28*******_fraex'; // nome do banco de dados a ser usado

$dbpass = '**********'; // senha

$conecta = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

$seleciona = mysql_select_db($dbname);

// cria a instrução SQL que vai selecionar os dados

$query = sprintf("SELECT user_name, comentario FROM comentario ORDER BY coment_id desc limit 5");

// executa a query

$dados = mysql_query($query, $conecta) or die(mysql_error());

// transforma os dados em um array

$linha = mysql_fetch_assoc($dados);

// calcula quantos dados retornaram

$total = mysql_num_rows($dados);
?>
```

Como posso resolver isso?

Comment: Esse tipo de conexão não é mais usada e é desencorajada pois é muito insegura para SQL Inject, use PDO no lugar por ser mais seguro.

Comment: e como eu poderia mudar isso para PDO?

Answer (score 0):

Esta mensagem não é um erro e sim um "aviso".

A função `mysql` será removida do PHP muito em breve e a mensagem esta sugerindo que você use `mysqli_` ou `PDO`.

Você pode saber mais sobre o `mysqli` [na documentação oficial do PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysqli-connect.php), e também pode consultar como usar o `PDO` que é o mais recomendável.

Comment: ta mais eu precisaria mudar alguns termos ou teria que reestruturar os codigos?

Comment: Só alguns termos, você chegou a abrir o link que coloquei no post? nele tem um exemplo do `mysqli_connect` que você deveria usar no lugar de `mysql_connect` e assim por diante, veja a trecho que você usa com `mysql_` e procure o `mysqli_` que corresponda.